# Does this plugin convert pages in wordpress as well as posts?

Tags: wordpress, amp-html

I have installed another wordpress plugin to provide AMP conversion but that only works on Posts and not on the website pages which forms the greater part of the website and in effect is more important than posts.

Does this plugin work with both pages and posts or as with the other just posts?

Thanks

Adrian

Answer (score 0):

Automattic official [AMP plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/amp/) only supports posts and custom posts type, not archives or pages